# Custom breadboard manufacturers

Tags: audio, synthesizer

I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange for this, but I'm interested in whether it's possible to get some custom breadboards made. That is some solderless prototyping breadboards with a couple of extra tracks and connectors.

My first googling shows me lots of custom PCB makers, and a lot of standard breadboard manufacturers that offer custom colours etc. but not much else.

I'm mainly interested in developing audio / synths / noise machines etc.

What I'm looking for is something very like this:

[image]

But with extra tracks for sound in parallel with the power tracks, that are connected to audio-jack sockets. Possibly via an amplifier.

This would simplify what I do, and I think it would interest other musical hacker / makers.

I'm possibly interested in trying to run a crowd-funder for this, but before getting to that stage I just want to find out who to talk to about this kind of thing. What kind of companies might be able to make it etc.

Does something like this exists already?

My main interest is as a potential customer.

Anyone got any pointers?

Comment: That image isn't a custom breadboard. It's off-the-shelf breadboard pieces glued to a piece of metal. The [NI Digital Electronics FPGA Board](https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/372809b.pdf) has something similar to what you're looking for, but I'm not sure who the vendor is. Someone suspected it might have been 3M but I don't have a reliable source, and even if it was 3M it was likely a custom product.

Comment: If the cost of producing it is a consideration, it makes more sense to design a printed circuit board assembly that uses some existing off the shelf socket parts to mimic the breadboard sockets and then use the underlying PCB to route it all as make senses for its intended use. There would be quite high tooling costs to come up with a custom breadboard like monolithic part that also contains the needed routing.

Comment: I am sure I saw breadboard-like components that can be mounted on PCB, so you might be able to build your own. Unfortunately can't find any references.

Comment: i would glue many cheap/small breadboards to a backer board. The rails come off the medium size ones, which provides a nice two-lane strip. I've made custom PCBs that are like tiny breadboards, which come in handy all the time. You can do a lot with female socket headers, IC sockets, jumpers, screw terminals, jacks, etc; on a fixed PCB that allows a lot of swap-outs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that it would meet your needs, but Mimmotronics' Protis 1 prototype board has worked well for me in prototyping audio circuits for guitar, eurorack, etc.  It's very well put together and has pretty much everything I need in a board of this type. You can take a gander at it here:  https://mimmotronics.com/protis1/.  Also check out the add-on modules for it.

I'm not affiliated in any way with Mimmotronics, btw, just a satisfied customer.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah... that looks interesting. It's definitely solves the problem. Though it's a lot more complex than I imagined. And more expensive. I was literally looking for something more or less at the same price as as big breadboard ($20-$30) that saved me having to do the standard audio connections.

Comment: Looking at the pictures on that board lead me to: http://busboard.com/breadboards. Looks like you could buy extra power rail sections to attach to one of their conventional breadboards.